# Responsive website doesn't appear "responsive" on phones

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, when I resize the width of browser window on PC, everything looks splendid, all elements relocate like they should. But when I visit this page on phone - it just loads the full website zoomed out, so it fits all the page, which looks like a fullscreen on PC, with minute letters and images, as if I didn't waste hours making it responsive! Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you checked if the page loads the bootstrap CSS? The "media" on CSS is what sets different layouts for different screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the viewport meta tag? If not, I think it might be the way to go:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Indeed. Check the basic HTML template in Bootstrap's [Getting Started](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) guide; it'll include the viewport meta and other things you may need.