# website input fields and buttons do not look normal on phone

Tags: html, css

I made this very simple website that takes a string and converts it to the style of an album. It works fine on pc but it's not responsive on my phone.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22440390/responsive-website-doesnt-appear-responsive-on-phones) and some other posts but they doesn't solve my problem.

How can I do this using plain css.

| This is what i get | I expect something like this |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Image of the output] | [image: Image of output similar to what i expect] |

this is my code

```js
function TA13OO1ZH() {
  var word = document.getElementById("str").value
  if (word !== "") {
    word = word.toUpperCase();
    result = word.replaceAll("B", "13")
    result = result.replaceAll("I", "1")
    result = result.replaceAll("S", "Z")
    const out = word + ' | ' + result;
    // change text on page
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = out
    document.getElementById('copy-btn').hidden = false
    document.getElementById("str").style.width = "900px"
  }


}

function clear1nputz() {
  document.getElementById('str').value = "";
  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('copy-btn').hidden = true
  document.getElementById("str").style.width = "500px"
}

function copyText() {
  var Text = document.getElementById("out").textContent
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(Text);
}
```

```css
.textbox {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.textbox>input {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

#str {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  width: 500px
}

input {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.multi-button {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow) 4px 4px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

 :root {
  --colour-black: #1e1e1e;
  --colour-white: #ffffff;
  --font-size: 100%;
}

button,
.button {
  --button: hsl(0, 0%, 12%);
  --button-hover: hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
  --button-active: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
  --button-visited: hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
  --button-colour: var(--colour-white);
  --button-border: var(--colour-black);
}

button {
  padding: .9rem 1.7rem;
  color: var(--button-colour);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background: var(--button);
  border: solid 1px var(--button-border);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px var(--colour-white);
  margin-right: 1em;
}

button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: var(--button-hover);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px var(--colour-white);
}

button:active {
  background: var(--button-active);
}

button:visited {
  background: var(--button-visited);
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(bg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<form style="  position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);transform: translate(-50%, -50%)">
  <input style="font-family: Times, serif; font-size: 17px" type="text" id="str" name="string">
</form>
<div>
  <div class="textbox">
    <div class="textbox">
      <br>
      <br>
      <p id="out" style="white-space: nowrap; font-family: Times, serif; font-size: 20px"></p>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="buttons" class="textbox" style="  display: flex; white-space: nowrap;">
      <br>
      <button style="font-family: Times, serif;" id="copy-btn" onclick="copyText()" hidden="">COPY TABOOISH | COPY TA13OO1ZH </button>
      <button style="font-family: Times, serif;" onclick="TA13OO1ZH()">SWITCH IT UP | ZWITCH 1T UP</button>
      <button style="font-family: Times, serif;" onclick="clear1nputz()">CLEAR | CLEAR</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<p class="textbox"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> <a href="https://github.com/ahmadlgohary" target="_blank">My Github </a> </p>
```

Comment: What's the problem? How does the result differ from your expectations?

Comment: Instead of posting a link and expecting others to know what isn't normal, please include what you're expecting (as an image).

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how the expected result is related at all to your CSS

Comment: @Phil I want a similar layout, I cannot get it to look how I want it to be, like how the buttons and text box fit in the screen

Comment: I have a feeling that `width: 500px` has a lot to do with the problem

Answer (score 0):

Once try giving the width in percentages instead of giving a constant `px` value. Because, when you give the width in `px` then it will be constant in every size of frame and when you give the size of the buttons or input text boxes in `%` form the size of the element will change according to the screen size. Learn about this and try to apply this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to make the website responsive on your phone. With media query you can apply different styles based on the screen size.

Ex:

```
#str {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  width: 500px;

/* Add a media query for smaller screens (adjust the max-width as needed) */

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

In this example, the width will be 500px in larger screen sizes and 100% in small screen sizes of width 600px and below. You can also make the fonts smaller in smaller screen sizes etc, feel free to experiment as you want